# How can I do a publish operation in one revision?

Tags: svn, merge, content-management-system, overwrite

I am running a web based CMS on top of SVN.

I have a trunk/ and a prod/ branch.

I have a "publish" operation that I want to take the version in trunk and overwrite prod so that the trunk version is now production.

I am currently doing a delete prod and then copy trunk -> prod. This is not ideal as I have to do 2 operations, and I often run into deployment issues (it catches the delete and the add seperately and has to redownload everything in the folder. Can be costly if that folder has media files in it)

I have resisted trying to use merge because I need there to be no changes to prod, no unresolved merge conflicts, nothing. This is all automated, there is no human to handle any conflicts.

While the prod/ branch shouldn't have revisions except coming from trunk/ I don't want it to break if there are.

so, if I have:
/trunk/folder/newer-version.txt
/prod/folder/with-older-version.txt

I want an operation that will make the /prod/folder/ files be exactly the same as /trunk/folder, no more, no less.

```
svn merge trunk/folder prod/folder --accept mine-conflict
```

The concept I really want is copy --overwrite --delete-extras.

I am open to other concepts, but after a publish there must not be remnants of other revisions that weren't in the trunk@HEAD

Edit: 2nd Edit:
There are 3 priorities:
1) This operation will never fail with a merge conflict, or require interaction
2) if there is /prod/oldfile and no /trunk/oldfile, then the publish should delete the oldfile.
3) I cannot do this with a workspace. The possible sizes of these folders are too large to duplicate reasonably fast

If this should work normally, let me know and I will run through some more test cases.

Edit: one workaround is to use svnmucc, but I can't find any perl SWIG bindings for mucc.

Comment: "While the prod/ branch shouldn't have revisions except coming from trunk/ I don't want it to break if there are." - How would changes happen to that `prod` branch? What happens if there are changes there - are changes merged to trunk? Lock `prod` down so that those unexpected revisions can't happen (and you ought to be doing that anyway!) and you can use merges for this.

Comment: If changes were to happen on prod, then they should be overwritten. It is locked down, only admins have direct SVN access and could make commits to prod/.

Comment: So, what exactly are you worried about? Changes are not happening on prod, so you can just use merges. If somebody manages to make a change on prod then you can always revert it. Maybe as part of your release process, you could just compare the prod HEAD to the trunk HEAD to make sure they match, if you're paranoid (which can be healthy to some extent).

Comment: Will I have troubles switching to merging, because current systems are delete / copying from trunk, but not doing it to the whole folder. and not using merge?

Comment: The issue is I don't have a good workspace area to merge into. I am told that you can't merge repository to repository.

Comment: Correct, you can't merge repo-to-repo, you'll need a working copy. But that shouldn't be a problem. Not doing it to whole folders may cause problems with merging depending on how fine-grained you do things; but SVN is perfectly capable of merging single files. It's just not a very nice way to handle merges. Make sure to be extra careful to commit exactly the mergeinfo SVN calculates.

Comment: I need to be able to do this operation on folders. And those folders could have folders and subfolders, and those could have large size media files. And any revision that finishes triggers a post commit hook to do svn update on my web server. So, doing a delete, then add, means it deletes everything, and then re-downloads it. which is bad if you have 15gig in a folder.